# PHP login page using session variable

Tags: php, session

I am new to php, and trying to create a login page through session without using database, if user successfully logs in, it will be redirected to some page "portfolio.php” and then session will expire after 15 mins but if user randomly types the “portfolio.php” as url it will be redirected to the login page. it should only redirect to that page ("portfolio.php") after the user has login successfully.
here is my "login.php" page code:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include("functions.php");
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    if( $_POST["user_name"] == "admin" and $_POST["password"] == "admin-1") {
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = 1001;
        $_SESSION["user_name"] = $_POST["user_name"];
        $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();  

    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    if(!isLoginSessionExpired()) {
        header("Location:portfolio.php");
    } else {
        header("Location:logout.php?session_expired=1");
    }
}
if(isset($_GET["session_expired"])) {
    $message = "Login Session is Expired. Please Login Again";
}
?>
```

portfolio.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("functions.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    if(isLoginSessionExpired()) {
        header("Location:logout.php?session_expired=1");

    }
 }

?>
```

funcation.php code:

```
<?php
function isLoginSessionExpired() {
    $login_session_duration = 10; 
    $current_time = time(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) and isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){  
        if(((time() - $_SESSION['loggedin_time']) > $login_session_duration)){ 
            return true; 
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“it will be redirected to the login page, instead it should only redirect to that page after the user has login successfully”_ – what, you want it to redirect to the login page only _after_ login? That does not make much sense.

Comment: You need to update your explanation, its confusing.

Comment: What exactly is the issue ? and where is the login form ? also, Is that `$_GET["session_expired"]` line in the 'login.php' a typo ?

Comment: I want a secure page in which the user can see the page only when the user has successfully logged in to that page (demo.php ) and not by typing the url for the page as given above. When the session expires the user should get back to the login page only ( login.php ). The problem is that the user is able to move back to the previous page, I don't want that to happen.
Is it possible that after the session expires by clicking on the back button on the browser the page(demo.php) should not be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code...
You should change `$login_session_duration = 10;` to   `$login_session_duration = 900;` for 15 mins

and your portfolio.php should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("funcation.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    if(isLoginSessionExpired()) {
        header("Location:login.php?session_expired=1");    
    }
 } else {
     header('Location:login/index(ur html input file)');
 }  

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it,s work.

Comment: @Shubham no problm

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't set any check in `portfolio.php` file.
Try to check if session login is valid for every php page you create. For example add a session helper in your functions.php file:

```
function session_helper() {
  if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
      if(isLoginSessionExpired()) {
        header("Location:logout.php?session_expired=1");
      }
      // check valid user id?
      // session is fine, let the code continue
  } else {
    // no session user_id so redirect to login or 
    // any other welcome page

    header("Location:login.php");   
  }

}
```

then you could use that method in all your files, including the `portfolio.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // the new functions.php file
    include("functions.php");
    session_helper();

    // more code
?>
```

If you are planning to do a php application, you can consider using a [Php Framework](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) which handles a lot of stuff for you and cares about security issues you may not be aware of, as well as providing built-in safer user authentication.

Comment: There's a secure page and I want people to sign up with the given Name & Email ID. Also, I want to verify the Email ID. This is what I'm trying to do as I have a requirement in which the user gets the link for the page and then only they can access it. Can you plaese help me with this?

Comment: you could reformulate your question..